# How can evaluate if AWS OpenSearch Serverless will be cost-effective?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

We're currently using AWS OpenSearch Service, the traditional way in which you provision nodes. Recently, Amazon OpenSearch Serverless went GA, and we find interest in this option.

My question is, how can I assess if this will be a good choice for us? What are the metrics I should inspect in order to tell if moving to Serverless will be cost-effective for us?

Answer (score 0):

As per stated in [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/pricing/), you will be billed separately for compute and storage capacity. For compute, it is based on OCUs, and for storage for data stored in S3. You're billed for a minimum of 4 OCUs (1 OpenSearch Compute Unit = 6 GB of RAM + vCPU + gp3 + data transfer) for the first collection in your account, and you can configure a maximum number of OCUs for your account in order to control costs. These OCUs always exist, even when there's no indexing or search activity. That means that if you need autoscaling then “serverless” is a good choice, and you can easily calculate the price of a service and compare it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).